# AngularJS select - match first characters

Tags: angularjs, search, select

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

This search plugin finds a match using `'LIKE %word%'`. Possible to change it to `'LIKE word%'`
Example: If I type letter 'T' when searching states, currenty it returns following:
H**I**
**I**D
**I**L
**I**N
**I**A
M**I**
R**I**
...

I'd like it to return:
**I**D
**I**L
**I**N
**I**A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality by using angular's custom filter.
Something like:

```
app.filter('propsFilter', function() {
  return function(items, props) {
    var out = [];
    if (angular.isArray(items)) {
      items.forEach(function(item) {
        var keys = Object.keys(props);
        var prop = keys[0];
        var text = props[prop].toLowerCase();
        if (item[prop].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) === 0) {
          out.push(item);
        }
      });
    } else {
      out = items;
    }
    return out;
  };
});
```

and pass this filter into out select2 declaration:

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="select2" class="form-control" title="Choose a person">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="item in people | propsFilter: {name:$select.search}">
              <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
              <small ng-bind-html="item.email | highlight: $select.search"></small>
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ti6CkdA38cEPJIvXLnDV?p=preview) is the plunkr link you can refer: